# Defining custom css styles for html tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't do CSS and I'm not even sure what this is called so excuse the ignorance :-)

```
.examples {
 }

.examples b {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.examples p {
  margin-top: 0.9em;
  margin-bottom: 0.9em;
}
```

I'm assuming the above means any `b` or `p` tags inside a `<div class='examples'>` will use the styling from `.examples` and anything custom defined for `b` or `p`?

Can I create my own style using that convention, like this?

```
.examples mystyle {
}

<div class='examples'>
   <div class='mystyle'>
   ...
```

### UPDATE:

I want `mystyle` to use `examples` styling, but override with a black bottom border. Using `.examples .mystyle` the bottom border appears outside `examples` div, but with `.examples mystyle` the enclosing div looks good, but the bottom black border is gone. My apologies, so it's not working either way.

http://jsfiddle.net/SAFX/5ft9W/

Comment: Your `div` doesn't appear to be inside of any element, let alone an element with the class of `examples`. Please take the time to read about CSS selectors: [Selectors, Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

Comment: .examples .mystyle {        }              It's valid

Comment: @DavidThomas sorry, I am using `mystyle` inside `examples`, so they're called selectors?

Comment: @raffian Is the CSS selector actually `.examples .mystyle` (with a dot)? If so, you might want to fix the typo because it distracts people to answer the wrong question.

Comment: @raffian: maybe you could be a bit more explicit in describing your question? I think you’re under a bit of a misapprehension about how CSS works (which is fine), but it’s difficult to help without you explaining what you think your code should do in more detail.

Comment: @Juhana No, not a typo, I got it working `.examples mystyle`, but what's the difference?

Comment: It won't actually do anything unless you have an element `<mystyle>`. It'd be great to see a complete example.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite good idea, I'll create a fiddle..

Comment: @Juhana That would make the HTML invalid.  Is it invalid CSS to use a tag selector for tag that doesn't exist?

Comment: @KevinBowersox It's invalid HTML, but most if not all modern browsers allow it so for the purposes of this question it *would* work.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite added jsfiddle

Comment: As to the update, once you correct the selector *to use the `.` you said you were using*, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5ft9W/2/).

Comment: As I said, `.examples mystyle` does nothing (c.f. http://jsfiddle.net/5ft9W/3/). With the dot the rules apply correctly, but apparently they're not the correct rules for what you want to achieve (perhaps [without the float](http://jsfiddle.net/5ft9W/4/)?)

Comment: @Juhana BINGO! sorry for the roller coaster ride, that worked great!

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using a class on the tag it would need to be a class selector and the element must be a child of `.examples`:

```
/* Notice the `.` on mystyle */
.examples .mystyle {
}

<div class="examples">
    <div class='mystyle'></div>
</div>
```

There are several parts to a CSS style:

```
.examples .mystyle { /* selector */
   font-weight: bold;  /* This entire line is a declaration consisting of a property & value*/
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing, `mystyle` is inside `examples` div, should have mentioned that.

Comment: @KevinBowersox `.examples mystyle {` works, but `.mystyle` does not work, the formatting from `examples` does not extend to the child div.

Comment: @raffian Does the `.examples .mystyle` style override any properties set in `.examples`?

Comment: @raffian: I suspect your `.examples mystyle` styles aren’t actually working how you think they are. Maybe you could be a bit more explicit about what you expect your code to do.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I don't see how he is getting any styles applied with `.examples mystyle`

Comment: @raffian The style floats the div to the left however you specify 100% width.   Do you need the float?  http://jsfiddle.net/5ft9W/1/

Comment: @KevinBowersox: yup — I think he doesn’t yet know how CSS selectors work, or what they are.

Comment: @KevinBowersox That was the issue, the float; I'm a backend guy, you guys have it easy with this css stuff :-)

Comment: @raffian I'm a jack of all trades, backend (db, server) front end (html,css,js).  The front end isn't all that great, it gets really crazy with cross browser compliance and the quirks of each browser.

Answer (score 2):

What you *seem* to be asking about is the terminology to describe child elements inheritance of style from an ancestor; this is the 'cascade' of 'Cascading Style Sheets.' Not all elements inherit from their parents/ancestors (`a` links, notably, do not inherit the `color` property by default, though specifying `color: inherit;` in their css declaration can make them do so).

If you're asking about how to refer to the list of selectors that determine which elements are targeted by a particular rule, that is the 'selector', or 'selector expression.'

References:

- [CSS (from the Mozilla Developer Network, 'MDN')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS).
- [Introduction to CSS 2.1 (from the W3C)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/intro.html).
- [Selectors, Level 3 (from the W3C)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).